# SSO (Single Sign-On) using JHipster UAA

Tags: single-sign-on, owin, jhipster, cloudfoundry-uaa

How can I implement `3rd party Single Sign-On (SSO)` with `JHipster UAA`? 3rd party authentication uses `OWIN` based auth in `.Net`. Do I need `keycloak` in place on `JHipster UAA`?

Comment: UAA has less support in JHipster compared to KeyCloak/Okta, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13081 so I would rather use KeyCloak/Okta

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou. Is there any way I can migrate my UAA based Microservice stack to Keycloack ?

Comment: You change the option in your .yo-rc.json file then re-generate your project then you carefully replace/merge modified files using git diff.